# Nginx reverse proxy /some-path to the root path of another server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

We have been trying to get nginx to work as a reverse proxy for a few days and have had no luck so far.Here is the scenario that we want to make work:

We have two applications running on two different servers and we want to serve them under the same domain. The main application (`mydomain.com`) is served using nginx. We want to be able to serve the second application at `mydomain.com/app2` and redirect all requests to `mydomain/app2` to the root path of the second application (including all its sub-paths)

The second app currently runs on a subdomain (`app2.mydomain.com`). Here is an example of what we want to do:

`mydomain.com/app2` should be served form `app2.mydomain.com`

`mydomain.com/app2/users` should be served from `app2.mydomain.com/users`

`mydomain.com/users` should just be served from `mydomain.com/users`

So far we have not been able to find the right configuration in nginx to be able to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Cheers
Sina